# Getting the full url for an image in webpage

Tags: html, css, firebug, firefox-addon

I would like to get the full url of an image in a web page. The image is used as a background image. I was using Firebug's inspect feature. In the CSS view, it shows url(/images/myimage.gif) for the background-image element.

Is there a way to display the full url?

Comment: Do you need to get it programmatically, or manually from the browser (and Firefox specifically, even)? This question belongs on SuperUser if it's the latter.

Comment: It's manually but let's not nitpick on this as to which site it goes to.  It's used when I am doing css/html stuff so it's programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the path in FireBug's style inspector and select 'Copy Image Location.'

Answer (score 0):

Well the full URL will be your current URL location,  minus the last .html or .php etc file name, plus /images/myimage.gif.

So on example.com/blah.html

the mentioned URL would be

example.com/images/myimage.gif

If you're trying to get firebug itself to expand and show the FULL url, you can also right click in the inspector and choose "show image location".  But that's one way to do it.

Another way is to right click the image, and in Chrome you can choose "Copy image URL" which would give you that full address.  Just checked - Firefox also has "Copy image location" which would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To get the full path to a background image, you don't need Firebug.  In FF, just put your cursor on the background image, right click and choose View Background Image.  The full path will be in the address area of the browser window.